# C# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, formatexception

I am receiving a FormatException error sometimes when running the below code.  The exception seems to be thrown at random. Members of my team have seen the error while running the code and will inform me.  Within seconds I will try to insert the same data using the same app and not get it the exception.  I have attached an example of the format exception text below.  The exception implies that I am trying to convert a decimal to an int32, but in the values below that I am assigning, none are decimal or int. Has anyone come across a format exception like this?

```
foreach (var strPriceFile in lstPriceFiles)
{
    var SoldToRecs = DbContext.RFQ_SoldTo_PriceLists.Where(us => us.UserId == ERepGuid && us.RFQ_SoldTo_CustNbr == strSoldTo[0] && us.RFQ_SoldTo_CustSeq == strSoldTo[1] && us.IngresFileName == strPriceFile);

    if (SoldToRecs.Count() == 0)
    {
        var PriceFile = new RFQ_SoldTo_PriceList();
        PriceFile.UserId = ERepGuid;
        PriceFile.RFQ_SoldTo_CustNbr = strSoldTo[0];
        PriceFile.RFQ_SoldTo_CustSeq = strSoldTo[1];
        PriceFile.IngresFileName = strPriceFile;
        PriceFile.CreatedBy_UserName = strCreatorName;
        PriceFile.CreatedBy_DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        PriceFile.Active_YN = true;

        DbContext.RFQ_SoldTo_PriceLists.InsertOnSubmit(PriceFile);
    }
}
```

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>      System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +12630933
>      System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +224
>      System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter.FromString(String value, NumberFormatInfo formatInfo) +46
>      System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value) +497
>
> [Exception: 90.90908893868948 is not a valid value for Int32.]
>      System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value) +8019613
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +938181
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +227
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.AssignToPropertyOrField(Object propertyValue, Object o, String memberName, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError) +321
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2 dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +1790
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +115
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +227
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(String input) +126
>      Telerik.Web.UI.RadListBox.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +184
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +1018
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2653

Comment: You're trying to deserialize into an `int` property.

Comment: The exception is not lying to you. The string is in the wrong format. Catch the exception, display the string, and you'll see what's wrong with the format.

Comment: That error looks like your code is calcuating the double floating point (not decimal) number 90.1 (approximately). Likely whatever is generating the JSON isn't trimming the double to an int.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue may caused by Google Chrome zoom-in/out issue, as long as your are using **RadScheduler, RadListBox, and RadTreeView**, as stated by **Hristo Valyavicharski** in the links below. In this case, you can reproduce this issue by zooming-in or out on Google Chrome and perform postback again.

The work-around for this issue can be found here:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/system-formatexception-78e82e51af27#KkKRUtkEq0ST4A09XY_eZQ

You can see the explanation here:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/system-formatexception-78e82e51af27#Ww7bQEwfgUiShf9gFFmxBg

Below are the fixes provided by **Hristo Valyavicharski**:

For RadScheduler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Telerik.Web.UI.RadScheduler.prototype.saveClientState = function () {
    return '{"scrollTop":' + Math.round(this._scrollTop) + ',
    "scrollLeft":' + Math.round(this._scrollLeft) + ',
    "isDirty":' + this._isDirty + '}';
} </script>
```

For RadTreeView:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeView.prototype.saveClientState = function () {
    return "{\"expandedNodes\":" + this._expandedNodesJson +
    ",\"collapsedNodes\":" + this._collapsedNodesJson +
    ",\"logEntries\":" + this._logEntriesJson +
    ",\"selectedNodes\":" + this._selectedNodesJson +
    ",\"checkedNodes\":" + this._checkedNodesJson +
    ",\"scrollPosition\":" + Math.round(this._scrollPosition) + "}";
} </script>
```

For RadListBox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadListBox.prototype.saveClientState = function() {
        return "{" +
                    "\"isEnabled\":" + this._enabled +
                    ",\"logEntries\":" + this._logEntriesJson +
                   ",\"selectedIndices\":" + this._selectedIndicesJson +
                   ",\"checkedIndices\":" + this._checkedIndicesJson +
                   ",\"scrollPosition\":" + Math.round(this._scrollPosition) +
               "}";
    } </script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Updated.